Exiting diff mode in vifm
I recently discovered vifm's :compare command. What a timesaver that has been! What I can't find is a way to get back to the normal view. I tried :diffoff, thinking it might mirror the vim command, but no luck. I also read through the help document without finding any answer.
Is there a command to leave the [diff] mode? Or do I need to exit and restart vifm?

Documentation can definitely do a better job on this, but :compare uses custom views under the hood.  You might already know that any command which changes current directory of a view implicitly closes custom view if it's active (typically, h or gh get used to exit it). There is also :regular command to do that explicitly.

I wasn't aware of the custom views. So much to explore in this program. h is definitely the quickest way out. Thanks, xaizek.
